# Borrar en cascada en MySQL en una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos de MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE ex_tag(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    tag_id_fk INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tag_id_fk) REFERENCES tags(tag_id)
);

CREATE TABLE solution(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    solution_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags(
    tag_id INT,
    tag_name VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(tag_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

Mi intención es hacer una tabla desde PHP que muestre los ejercicios y al lado, tener un botón de eliminar para poder borrar de la BBDD el ejercicio seleccionado.

El problema es que tengo que borrar de las tablas anteriores el ejercicio uno por uno porque tienen relación. De esta manera:

```
delete from solution where exercise_id_fk = 10;
delete from ex_tag where exercise_id_fk= 10;
delete from exercises where exercise_id = 10;
delete from tags where tag_id = X;
delete from answers where exercise_id_fk = 10;
```

Me gustaría poder eliminar el ejercicio en una sola consulta como esta:

```
DELETE e, et, s, a
FROM exercises e 
LEFT JOIN ex_tag et 
    ON e.exercise_id= et.exercise_id_fk
LEFT JOIN solution s
    ON s.exercise_id_fk= et.exercise_id_fk
LEFT JOIN answers a
    ON a.exercise_id_fk= et.exercise_id_fk
WHERE e.exercise_id= "10";
```

El problema es que no me funciona y no sé cómo puedo combinar la tabla ‘tags’. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? gracias

Este es el error que me sale:

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`ex_tag`, CONSTRAINT `ex_tag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_id_fk`) REFERENCES `exercises` (`exercise_id`))
```

Comment: para esto debes cumplir con dos cosas .. *Primera* tu BD debe ser InnoDB.. *Segundo* tu Foreign Key debe tener algo como esto "ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE"

Comment: ya con esto puedes hacer algo asi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917374/5215609

Comment: O lo que te comentaron antes, o borras **en orden**. No podes borrar un registro primero del cual dependen otras tablas.

Comment: @DiegoAvila todas mis tablas son InnoDB, pero hay alguna alternativa a `ON DELETE CASCADE`? Ya que todas mis tablas están echas y pretendo no volver a crearlas...

Comment: @gbianchi borrar en orden te refieres a hacer todas las consultas de DELETE para todas las tablas necesarias?

Comment: Exactamente ana, pero en el orden correspondiente. no podes borrar primero de exercies, porque en muchas de las otras tablas van a quedar registros huerfanos (y ese el error que tenes).

Comment: @gbianchi se podría hacer en PHP? Borrando de una sola tabla sin foreign keys sería así: `mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id='".$id."'");`, pero para borrar de varias tablas cómo se puede hacer?

Comment: Porque lo queres hacer con una sola query? hace la cantidad de querys necesarias y envolvelas en una transaccion...

Comment: lo que sugiero es remover tu foreingkey y volver a agregarla con su metodo cascada para delete y update: https://www.5balloons.info/alter-table-to-remove-foreign-key-or-add-delete-cascade-mysql/